# As3: Get exact point of collision using hitTestPoint?

Tags: actionscript-3, collision, point, hittest, direction

I am using hitTestPoint to detect collisions between an enemy and a wall.

I want it so that if the enemy touches the wall, his new target direction should be changed to a point towards the opposite direction of the wall. To do this, I guess I need to know exactly where the enemy and the wall collided.

The main movement system:

```
    private function move(event:Event):void
    {

        var dx = target.x - x;
        var dy = target.y - y;
        var angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx)/Math.PI*180;
        rotation = angle;


        this.x = x+Math.cos(rotation/180*Math.PI)*movementSpeed;
        this.y = y+Math.sin(rotation/180*Math.PI)*movementSpeed;

        var hyp = Math.sqrt((dx*dx)+(dy*dy));

        if(hyp <5)
        {
            target.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1750 - 50 + 1) + 50);
            target.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (850 - 50 + 1) + 50);
        }
    }
```

And the wall detection system:

```
        while (_root.wall.hitTestPoint(this.x, this.y+radius, true)) 
        {
            this.y--;
            target.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (850 - 50 + 1) + 50);
        }

        while (_root.wall.hitTestPoint(this.x, this.y-radius, true))
        {
            this.y++;
            target.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (850 - 50 + 1) + 50);
        }

        while (_root.wall.hitTestPoint(this.x-radius, this.y, true)) 
        {
            this.x++;
            target.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1750 - 50 + 1) + 50);
        }

        while (_root.wall.hitTestPoint(this.x+radius, this.y, true)) 
        {
            this.x--;
            target.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1750 - 50 + 1) + 50);
        }
```

"_root.wall" is a movieclip with a bunch of different vector rectangles.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

By looking over your code, It seems your enemy is always walking 'forward' based on his rotation. This can come to your advantage because when he walks into a wall, the opposite direction of the wall will be in the opposite direction of the enemy's rotation.

soo, whenever he hits a wall, you can update the target position in a way similar to below:
(may not be exact since as3 rotation deals with the negatives and all that)

```
var range:int = int(Math.random()*maxDistance);
var r:Number = rotation/180*Math.PI + Math.PI;
target.y = Math.sin(r) * (minDistance + range);
target.x = Math.cos(r) * (minDistance + range);
```

Also, If you don't want it to be directly opposite of the wall you can add some randomization to the angle itself:

```
var range:int = int(Math.random()*maxDistance);
var sign:int = (Math.random() > .5) ? 1 : -1;
var r:Number = rotation/180*Math.PI + Math.PI + ((Math.random() > .5)? 1 : -1)*(Math.random()*Math.PI)/4;
target.y = Math.sin(r) * (minDistance + range);
target.x = Math.cos(r) * (minDistance + range);
```

Hope this helps.